# What do I need to watch to understand this character's history in an upcoming episode of "The Mandalorian"?

Tags: star-wars, suggested-order, the-mandalorian, ahsoka-tano

In *The Mandalorian* S2 E3, Mando is told to

> find a Jedi named **Ahsoka Tano.**

I'm aware this character is a major part of *The Clone Wars* series listening to friends. Since I have access to all of these episodes I would like to understand this character before the next episode of *The Mandalorian* comes out. However unfortunately I do not have the time between now and then to fully watch every episode available (at over 40 hours of content).

I was hoping someone may be able to recommend a selection of episodes I could watch to gain a good understanding of the character, their personality, their skills and major events in their character arc, etc. before continuing to the next chapter of *The Mandalorian*.

Comment: For a full realization of the awesomeness that is Ahsoka, you'll have to watch almost every one. The Clone Wars is as much about her as it is about Anakin Skywalker.
You could read her [Wookiepedia Bio](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano), but it doesn't do the character justice at all

Comment: I realise this, and am now keen to when time permits, but I'm also keen to not miss or delay watching the next episode when it comes out for fear of spoilers. I did think to read the Wookiepedia Bio, and thank you for linking it. My issue with that is it feels almost clinical compared to watching her story and since I have access to every episode I thought that watching the best of her would be better than reading the overview. I'm in that weird position of having watched all the films and now The Mandalorian and am starting to realise just how much of this universe I have yet to enjoy.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: I've been watching the Clone Wars (pretty slowly) over the past few months, and I do feel like a slimmed-down viewing order could be really helpful for people who are mainly interested in the tie-ins to The Mandalorian. I'm only about two-thirds through season 2, but there have been a bunch of episodes that, while fun and charming, would have been pretty skippable if I'm just looking to get the gist for later references.

Comment: All you need to know is that she was Anakin's apprentice.  She was framed and nearly expelled from the Jedi but was so disgusted by how she was treated she left anyway and avoided the purge.  Since then she has been like a wandering Ronin and had a large role in the early Rebellion.

Comment: **Mildest of spoilers:** We don't know yet, since we don't know what role she plays or what history she will reveal on her own in the coming episode(s).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Spoilers ahead

The problem here is Ahsoka Tano is a central character to both the *Clone Wars* TV series, as well as *Star Wars: Rebels*. It's like asking which Harry Potter books explain Hermione Granger (answer: all of them). I mean [Ahsoka's Wookieepedia page is fairly long](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano)

But a small guide can help here.

1. [Star Wars: The Clone Wars](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(film)) (99 minute theatrical release movie, not the series) - Introduces Ahsoka, who is assigned by Master Yoda to be Padawan to Anakin Skywalker. Chronologically this movie precedes the series, and shows more of Anakin and Ahsoka building the master-padawan relationship.
2. This one is too large so adding a spoiler block here. This is a pretty pivotal moment for Tano. You'll want to watch *Clone Wars* Season 5 episodes 18 through 20 (technically starts in 17 but you can skip it since the recap is enough)

   > Ahsoka is framed for a bombing at the Jedi temple. While she is ultimately cleared, the betrayal she feels (especially from Skywalker and Yoda) leads her to walk away from the Jedi Order.
3. Ahsoka and Bo-Katan do a lot in *Clone Wars* Season 7. Episodes 9 and 10 cover the end of the Siege of Mandalore (if Bo-Katan is around this could play into future episodes)
4. [Twilight of the Apprentice](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Twilight_of_the_Apprentice) (*Rebels* S2E21-22) Ahsoka faces a Sith temple where she confronts her old master
5. [A World Between Worlds](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/A_World_Between_Worlds) (*Rebels* S4E13) Explains what happened to Tano in *Twilight of the Apprentice*
6. [Family Reunion – and Farewell](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Family_Reunion_%E2%80%93_and_Farewell) (*Rebels* S4E15) Last canon mention of Tano

A good optional view here would be [The Lawless](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lawless) (*Clone Wars* S5E16) - Obi-Wan is rescued by Bo-Katan on Mandalore and it gives you some context for how Bo-Katan is in line to rule Mandalore.